# Toast is not being displayed from touch handler

Tags: android, toast, android-toast

So I have this block of code in my main Activity's onCreate() method; it installs a touch listener on a view that, when the touch is held for at least 5 seconds, enables a special debugging mode.

```
  findViewById(R.id.MainSetupFooterLayout).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
     long touchStarted;

     @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
           touchStarted = System.currentTimeMillis();
           return true;
        }
        else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
           long touchTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - touchStarted;
           if (touchTime >= 5000) {
              changeDebug();
              invalidateOptionsMenu();

              Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainSetupActivity.this,
                                           "Debug option " + (debugMode ? "enabled" : "disabled"),
                                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
              toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
              toast.show();
           }
           return true;
        }
        return false;
     }
  });
```

I've proven to myself that all the code runs and works exactly as desired (e.g., the changeDebug() method has a side effect of causing other UI changes which do occur), plus I can step through all this in the debugger.  The problem is: the Toast is *never* displayed.

I've verified that the onTouch() handler is being called on the main (UI) thread.  I've tried explicitly running the toast-related code on the UI thread [using runOnUIThread()], even though it already should be on that thread.

Beyond that, I'm totally at a loss as far as figuring out why the toast is not displaying.

Any ideas, suggestions, etc. would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!
randy

Comment: have you tried Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), etc...instead?

Comment: I have, yes.  Same problem exists.  I even tried creating a local (to the onCreate() method) variable containing the context, but it, too, behaved the same way.

Comment: are you destroying any views in the changeDebug?

Comment: is Toast object creating? did you debug?

Comment: @AmitK.Saha, yes, the Toast object looks OK to me.

Comment: @BojanKseneman, inside of changeDebug(): a variable is being inverted, and a button's enabled property is toggled, and a Log message is being written.  I even tried taking out those other two method calls, and the same thing happens.

Comment: Then that isn't the problem... i'm kind of lost. Comment out the gravity line?

Comment: your Toast is fine. I just ran in my hello world. can you see what happens if you just put the Toast snippet at the beginning of onTouch() ?

Comment: can you try getBaseContext() instead of MainSetupActivity.this ??

Comment: @AmitK.Saha, I tried that, and getApplicationContext(), no difference.  And, putting it in the touch down event doesn't work either.  I'm guessing there must be something funky with my view hierarchy?

Comment: Could be "very funky". at this point I am clueless why your Toast is not showing though your Toast snippet is absolutely fine. what about a simple Toast as we generally write them? e.g. Toast.makeText(MainSetupActivity.this,
                                           "Debug option " + (debugMode ? "enabled" : "disabled"),
                                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: I have coded Toast inside onTouch() for differenct action & that worked properly. don't know what is the problem in  your case. :|

Answer (score 0):

Try to put it before the two methods.

Comment: Didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Works in the emulator, and works on a different device.

Problem found: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35013

@#%$@&!

Thanks everyone who tried to help out.
randy